# $newElems.imagesLoaded is not a function When I using lightbox in Masonry

Tags: ajax, fancybox, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I am making a music sharing website like pinterest.

I use Masonry to make the grid layout and Infinite-Scroll load the next page. When I click a music album, it pops a lightbox (using fancybox) and loads some information with ajax.

On the first page, everything goes right. But after I click one music album, closed it and scrolled down the page, the new loaded part has this problem: `$newElems.imagesLoaded is not a function`

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Any help will be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
var $container = $('#container');
// masonry init
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    columnWidth: 100
  });
});
// ancybox fancybox
function init(){
    $("a.inline").fancybox({ 

         'transitionIn' : 'fade',
                 'transitionOut' : 'none',
                 'speedOut' : 0,
                 'hideOnOverlayClick': true,
                 'hideOnContentClick': false,
                 'overlayColor' : '#FFF',
                 'overlayOpacity' : 0.5,
                 'showCloseButton' : true,
                 'showNavArrows' : false
         });
}

init();

$container.infinitescroll({
  // infinitescroll init
  navSelector  : '#page-nav',    
  nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  
  itemSelector : '.item',    
  loading: {
      finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
      img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
    }
  },
  // infinitescroll callback
  function( newElements ) {
    var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
      $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, {
       isAnimated: false
       }, function () {
          // for new loaded part
              init();
         });

    });
  }
);
```

Comment: Try fancybox v2.x which supports dynamically added elements.